# An equality from Fritz John's paper

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Prove: $\frac{\rho}{(4\pi)^2}\int_{|\xi|=1}d\omega_\xi\int_{|\eta|=1}f(x^0+r\xi+\rho\eta)d\omega_\eta=\int_{|r-\rho|}^{r+\rho}\frac{\lambda}{8\pi r}d\lambda\int_{|\zeta|=1}f(x^0+\lambda\zeta)d\omega_{\zeta}$,

where $d\omega_\eta$ is unit spherical area element. $r, \rho, \lambda >0$, $\xi, \eta, \zeta$ are all unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$,  $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^3$(This is an equality in Fritz John's paper "blow-up of solutions of nonlinear wave equations in three dimensions")

I know we can calculate it by placing the region into a spherical shell, but I can't get the precisely form in the right and is there any other way to prove it?

Comment: What is $t$ on the rhs? And what are the limits on the outer integral on the rhs: $r+t-$what? (too small, unreadable).

Comment: Also, the identity is false: if $\rho$ is sufficiently large, $r$ sufficiently small, and $f$ nonnegative and compactly supported in a ball of sufficiently small radius, then the integral on the left is zero (because the integrand is zero) and the integral on the right is not. So you maybe have not mentioned some important additional information.

Comment: @Vladimir I am so sorry, my bad. I rewrite the original equality because the original one has some other irrelevant quantities. I have revised my mistakes. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I do not have the time to carefully write out all constants, so I only sketch the computation. Set $x_0=0$ without loss of generality. Next, denote $r\xi=x$, $\rho\eta=y$, $\lambda\zeta=z$. Clearly, as $x$ and $y$ vary over their spheres of radii $r$ and $\rho$, respectively, $z$ varies in the spherical layer $|r-\rho|\le z\le r+\rho$; for fixed $z$, both $r$ and $\rho$ vary on a circle (imagine a triangle with sides $\rho,r,|z|$; the circle is drawn by the vertex opposite to the side of length $|z|$ as we rotate the triangle around that side). Now it is clear that we should represent the integral on the LHS as an integral over that layer of the integral over the circle. 
We have $\omega_\xi=\operatorname{const} r^{-3}\Omega_x$, where $\Omega_x$ is the Leray form
$$
 \Omega_x=x_1dx_2\wedge dx_3+x_2dx_3\wedge dx_1+x_3dx_1\wedge dx_2.
$$ 
Since $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=r$, we have $x_1dx_1+x_2dx_2+x_3dx_3=0$ and hence (in the chart where $x_1\ne0$)
$$
 \Omega_x=\frac r{x_1}dx_2\wedge dx_3.
$$
Likewise,
$$
 \Omega_y=y_1dy_2\wedge dy_3+\dots=\frac\rho{y_1}dy_2\wedge dy_3.
$$
If we take $z=x+y$, then routine computation shows that
$$
 \Omega_x\wedge\Omega_y=d^3z\wedge\alpha\equiv dz_1\wedge dz_2\wedge dz_3\wedge\alpha,
$$
where $\alpha=a_1d(x_1-y_1)+a_2d(x_2-y_2)+a_3d(x_3-y_3)$ and the vector $a=(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ is determined by the condition that the triple product of $z$, $x$, and $a$ is $2\rho r$.
Now (up to multiplicative constants) we can rewrite the integral on the LHS as
$$
LHS=\int f(z)d^3z\wedge\alpha
$$
and then compute the integral with respect to  $\alpha$ over the above-mentioned circle depending on $z$. This will give the RHS. Hopefully you can reconstruct what I have omitted from the computation and restore all constants etc.

Comment: Many thanks for your time. Actually, if this problem is in dimension 2, then it would be easy. because in the new big spherical layer, every point just be covered by two circles, so we just need integral over the new big circle (relative to $z$), then multiply 2. But in dimension 3, the value which indicate "how many times" cover one point in the new big spherical layer is really difficult to determine. I think this is the most difficult thing. Anyway, thanks for your advice. I will try it again according to your method.

Comment: @chuck This value is exactly given by the integral of $\alpha$ over the circle. I guess there is no difficulty in computing it other than the computations might be lengthy.

Comment: Thanks again. You give me a new way to think and compute this. I would try it tomorrow because I am not very familiar with form language, I need to review this area first :)